# How to use Argument to get path file as an input data to other script in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, arguments

I want to read a 2 of the text file (Byte2.txt and FB.txt), but I don't want to put the path on the script, I want to use an argument when I run the script from the command line to parsing the path to my script. My expectation, when I run the script from the command line :

```
 $PowerShell.exe Script.ps1 arg1 arg2
```

`arg1` represents the path of Byte.txt and `arg2` represent the path of FB.txt

This is what I did.

```
$file = $Args[0]
$Data = $Args [1]
$file_2 = Get-Content " "
$file_2
$Data_2 = Get-content " "
$Data_2
```

I execute that script from cmd :

```
$PS.exe Script.ps1 C:\User\Byte.txt C:\User\FB.txt
```

Comment: Please provide a little better explanation. I am having trouble understanding what you are after. Do you mean you want a line of code that will display where it is being run from?
`(Get-PSCallStack)[0].InvocationInfo.MyCommand.Source` will give you the full path of the script

Answer (score 0):

This is working well

```
Param(
      [parameter(mandatory=$true)][string]$arg1, $arg2
    )

    $file= Get-Content $arg1
    $file

    $Data= Get-Content $arg2
    $Data
```

Execute from cmd :

```
$PS.exe Script.ps1 -arg1 C:\User\Byte.txt -arg2 C:\User\FB.txt
```